# How to define parent and child relationship for item in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I want to make the relationship between a parent item and child item. Let us say for example

ITem01 Box is having 25 pieces,

Item02 Piece is equal to 1.

**Item02 is the child of Item01**. I don't know how to define in dynamics 365

Answer (score 1):

Go to Item02 Piece Entity and create a lookup (foreign key) attribute for Item01 Box Entity. This will create a many-to-one (N:1) relationship from Piece (N) to Box (1).

Or, in reverse create a 1:N relationship from Box to Piece Entity.